# getting deleted answers on a SO question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-answers

I asked a question over at SO: [One table view cell/row bigger than others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767533/one-table-view-cell-row-bigger-than-others-iphone-cocoa-touch)

There was an answer and I forgot who posted it but it was helpful until the person deleted it (I think because of a misunderstanding)

Can I get it back. Or can someone with 10K+ rep retrieve it and repost it?

Comment: There are no deleted answers on that question.

Comment: @mmyers - check the history of the oldest answer...

Comment: @ChrisF: Forgot there was a moderator involved already. Never mind.

Comment: Is it just on my end, or does [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767533/one-table-view-cell-row-bigger-than-others-iphone-cocoa-touch/2767958#2767958) (the one that wasn't deleted) have a no author visible?

Comment: @ccornet - seems OK to me.

Comment: @ChrisF Okay, when I checked in yesterday on FF, I could see the author, but today, back on IE8 (I was checking the question for a different reason), the author is invisible again! How bizarre...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct thing to do here is flag your own question for moderator attention with the above text.

But, this will work too :)